# python cgi listener gets empty paypal IPN

Tags: python, paypal, cgi, paypal-ipn

I am trying to set up a python cgi listener for paypal IPN, and I tried different things [including this](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/article_pdn_intro-outside). But eventually I see the notification sent from paypal, but it doesn't have any details.

This is the code I am using:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()  # for troubleshooting
import os, sys

query_string=os.environ['QUERY_STRING']
user_ip=os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
query=form.getvalue("query")
paymentDetails = sys.stdin.read()

print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print """

<html>
<head>
<title>Test IPN</title>
</head>

<body>
Query String = %s <br>
User IP = %s <br>
</body>

</html>

"""%(query_string,user_ip)

fopen=open('output.txt','a')
fopen.write('Query: %s\n'%str(query))
fopen.write('Environment: %s\n'%str(os.environ))
fopen.write('Payment Details: %s\n'%str(paymentDetails))
fopen.close()
```

And this is the output I get:

```
Query: None
Environment: {'TMP': '/tmp', 'CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/005/html', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache', 'SCRIPT_NAME': '/p/ipn.py', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '<address>Apache Server at aaaaa.net Port 80</address>\n', 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.0', 'QUERY_STRING': '', 'PATH': '/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin', 'CONTENT_LENGTH': '975', 'GD_PHP_HANDLER': 'x-httpd-php5', 'SERVER_NAME': 'aaaaa.net', 'REMOTE_ADDR': '173.0.81.1', 'SPI': 'TRUE', 'SERVER_PORT': '80', 'SERVER_ADDR': '00.000.0.0', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/005/html', 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/005/html/p/ipn.py', 'SERVER_ADMIN': 'support@ssss.net', 'SCRIPT_URI': 'http://aaaaa.net/p/ipn.py', 'HTTP_HOST': 'aaaaa.net', 'SCRIPT_URL': '/p/ipn.py', 'REQUEST_URI': '/p/ipn.py', 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*', 'SUBDOMAIN_DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/005/html', 'TEMP': '/005/tmp', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1', 'PHPRC': '/005/html/', 'REMOTE_PORT': '53764', 'REQUEST_SCHEME': 'http', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'UNIQUE_ID': 'Ur7jX63JxMsAADYmVf8AAACk'}
Payment Details:
```

In the link above, the notification script sends something to paypal to verify payment, but as you can see the payment details is an empty string. Where can the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use os.environ[`QUERY_STRING`] in a POST - it will always be empty.  It works for a GET.

You code

```
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
query=form.getvalue("query")
paymentDetails = sys.stdin.read()
```

returns an empty string for `paymentDetails` because `cgi.FieldStorage()` has *already read that information* from stdin, so there is nothing left for paymentDetails.

One solution (see [my blog post here](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2014/12/do-frameworks-get-in-way.html) and [another SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556949/in-a-python3-cgi-script-how-can-i-read-the-raw-form-data-in-a-post/27711349#27711349)) is to create the map yourself, also very easy.  Replace the above code with

```
paymentDetails = sys.stdin.read()
multiform = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query_string)
```

You can use multiform very similarly to `cgi.FieldStorage()` - the values are lists.  Slightly awkward.  For simplicity, I converted it into a simple dict holding only the 0th value from each list since my code has no duplicate query values, but YMMV.

**Caveat**: this is Python 3 code, not sure if Python 2 would need any changes