# In a Python3 CGI script, how can I read the raw form data in a POST?

Tags: python, post, python-3.x, paypal, cgi

Yes, I'm aware of `cgi.FieldStorage`, but, being some form of unordered dictionary, **it does not preserve the order** of the original data (see below for proof).  Since I wish to use this data with PayPal IPN, order is important [PayPal docs here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/), which say "...you must send back the contents in the exact order they were received..."

Alternatively, `os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')` looks perfect, however, **it seems to only work for a GET**.  Example code: (myscript.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi, os

query = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING') or 'no query'
print ("Content-type: text/plain\n\n")
print("query=" + query)
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
for key in form.keys():
   print("\n" + key + '=' + form.getvalue(key))
```

Works with a GET from the browser, e.g. (note that foo is *before* ggg)

```
http://example.com/myscript.py/foo=bar&ggg=3&aaa=bbb&zzz=qqq
```

returns

```
query=foo=bar&ggg=3&aaa=bbb&zzz=qqq
ggg=3
foo=bar   << note that foo now comes after ggg
aaa=bbb
zzz=qqq
```

However, if I use Postman to POST

```
POST /myscript.py HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar&ggg=3&aaa=bbb&zzz=qqq
```

It returns no query string, and, as expected, the FormData did not preserve the order.

```
query=no query
ggg=3
foo=bar   << note that foo now comes after ggg
aaa=bbb
zzz=qqq
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure why nobody answered.  After a little futzing I discovered that the solution is **incredibly simple**.  Is that why nobody bothered to answer?

Just read from stdin:  (this is Python3 code, not sure if Python2 would be any different)

`query_string = sys.stdin.read()`

There's one drawback: this is incompatible with `cgi.FieldStorage()`, since that will also try to read from stdin.  So, if you also want a nice dictionary to look up query terms, there is one more simple step:

`multiform = urllib.parse.parse_qs(query_string)`

which, much like cgi.FieldStorage, returns a [multimap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap), hence the name multiform.

For some more details, [I blogged about it here](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2014/12/do-frameworks-get-in-way.html).

Comment: You want to use `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` if you are processing binary data or data that can't be decoded using the current locale (which is usually wrong for the content type charset anyway).

Comment: ok. but `urllib.parse.parse_qs` fails to parse a file upload from `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="message"><input name="attachment" type="file"><input type="submit"></form>`. such form data can be parsed with [multipart](https://github.com/defnull/multipart), see also [multipart usage in CGI script multipart#47](https://github.com/defnull/multipart/issues/47)